# How to bind HBase standalone master to a specific port

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I'm running HBase in standalone mode from CDH 4.5 stack.
In conf/hbase-site.xml I put:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.port</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
```

But it still binds to a random port everytime I start it. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Have u checked port 60000 is free means not being used by any other component...

Comment: Yeah, it's free. If I switch to pseudo-distributed mode it binds to 60000 just fine. Looks like when in standalone it completely ignores configs.